# Resolving variable names from frame objects including non-locals

Tags: python

A Frame object as returned by `sys._getframe()` contains the members `f_locals` and `f_globals`, which should be self explaining. How can I correctly resolve variable names from a Frame object including non-local variables?

I would prefer a solution that would work both in Python 2 & 3.

```
def resolve_var(frame, name):
    if name in frame.f_locals:
        return frame.f_locals[name]
    # ... non-local variables here
    if name in frame.f_globals:
        return frame.f_globals[name]
    if hasattr(__builtins__, name):
        return getattr(__builtins__, name)
    raise NameError(name)
```

Comment: @Carpetsmoker It's both, Python 2 and 3. Ideally, it should be working in both versions.

Comment: Usually, you should tag something with a version-specific tag to indicate either which version you're using, or that this is a version-specific problem... Tagging both python-2 and python-3 and not having anything about it in the question is confusing...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure Python makes nonlocals available unless they textually appear in the source code of the function.  See for instance [`inspect.get_closure_variables()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/inspect.html#inspect.getclosurevars)